# MySQL update query updates one column but not other column

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL query successfully updated one of the two columns needed but not the other. The successful column, productionstage, is of data type: varchar and the unsuccessful column, floornotes, is of data type: text. I tested making the floornotes datatype: varchar with no success. The data for floornotes and productionstage come from an html form with its data sent through ajax to php. productionstage is a menu select and floornotes is a textarea. Any ideas on the issue? I don't get any errors from the server and when I do console.log() in my ajax for the passed floornotes value, I see the correct string each time.

MY CODE:

HTML:

```
<form id="workorderMovement" name='workorderMovement_form' action="workordermovementGET.php" method="post">



<fieldset id="userid">

  <span>Welcome <?php echo $user ?> </span>

</fieldset> 




<fieldset id="sgnum">

<fieldset id="fieldset" style="text-align: center;"> 
  <span>Please enter the SG Number</span>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="sgnumber" id="sgnumber"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" value="SEARCH">

</fieldset> 


<br/>
<br/>



<fieldset id="stageSelectField">

  <fieldset id="fieldset" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <span>Please select the Stage Completed</span>
  </fieldset>

<select name="stageSelect" id="stageSelect">
  <option value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
  <option value="Film Done">Film Done</option>
  <option value="Staged Done">Staged Done</option>
  <option value="Cleanroom Done">Cleanroom Done</option>
  <option value="GB2 Done">GB2 Done</option>
  <option value="Bagging Done">Bagging Done</option>
  <option value="Inspection Done">Inspection Done</option>
  <option value="LC Inspection Done">LC Inspection Done</option>
  <option value="IGU Done">IGU Done</option>
</select>

</fieldset> 


<br/>
<br/>


<fieldset id="floorNotesField">

  <fieldset id="fieldset" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <span>Please enter any new work order notes</span>
  </fieldset>

  <textarea type="text" name="floorNotes" id="floorNotes" class="floorNotesText"></textarea>

</fieldset>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</form> <!-- End Work Order Movement Form -->

<fieldset id="doneButtonField">

  <input type="button" name="doneButton" id="doneButton" value="DONE">

</fieldset>
```

MY AJAX:

```
         j("#doneButton").click(function(){


            //send Workorder Movement Data values to php using ajax.

                var sgnumber = j('#sgnumber').val();
                var stageselect = j('#stageSelect').val();
                var floornotes = j('#floorNotes').val();

             console.log(floornotes);

                j.ajax ({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "workordermovementUPDATE.php",
                    data: {sgNumber: sgnumber, stageSelect: stageselect, floorNotes: floornotes},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(){}
                 });

        });
```

MY PHP:

```
    <?php 


include('inc.php');


//Get Table Options.
if (isset($_POST['sgNumber'])) {
    $sgNumber = $_POST['sgNumber'];

    if (isset($_POST['stageSelect'])) {
        $stageSelect=$_POST['stageSelect'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['floorNotes'])) {
        $floorNotes=$_POST['floorNotes'];
    }

    //connect  to the database 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        printf('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $conn->select_db($dbname);

    if(! $conn->select_db($dbname) ) {
        echo 'Could not select database. '.'<BR>';
    }

    $sql= "UPDATE invoicesDec2016 SET productionstage = ?, floornotes = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $stageSelect, $floornotes, $sgNumber);
    $stmt->execute();       

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)){
        echo "".$sgnumber." Updated Successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not update ".$sgnumber."".mysqli_error($conn)."";
    }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//Free the result variable. 
 $result->free();


//Close the Database connection.
 $conn->close();

}//End If statement

?>
```

NOTE: When I do the update, productionstage updates successfully and previous floornotes content gets deleted.

Comment: Typo: Your variable is `$floorNotes` and not `$floornotes` (when you bind the placeholders in the sql). But you should probably add validation as well. And a table name with a year and a month in it sounds ... not right :-)

Comment: try echoing the variable right before the sql statement. My guess is you have variable error somewhere and empty string is being saved

Comment: @jeroen I'm testing off a backup of the real table. The date references the month the backup was made.

Comment: i've fixed the error with the variable name but I still have the issue. I even tried creating an entirely new column named 'sgfloornotes' with data type of text and redirected everything to that column, but upon updating, productionstage still works correctly, but sgfloornotes still won't. I also can't seem to do any kind of print_r() or echo of any variables within the php script... Any Ideas? –

Comment: And I just solved the error. Turns out my code editor and my server were having difficulties communicating so my edits never actually made it to the server... How annoying. However, all is well now. Thank you!