# UPDATE did not update two columns, but updated 13 others in the same row

Tags: sql, mariadb, centos7

I checked this question: [MySQL update query updates one column but not other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40998601/mysql-update-query-updates-one-column-but-not-other-column), but in that case the problem was that the file was not the correct version.

In my case, I have an automatically running UPDATE query that has worked 17882 times out of 17884 total runs (~99,99 % success rate :)) in MariaDB 10.1.19 on CentOS 7.

The values have been modified to protect the innocent. Note that this is automatically generated as-is:

```
UPDATE table AS t
SET workflow_id=376280614,
    list="list@client",
    contact=t.contactdate,
    fail_8=(t.fail_8 * 0.1),
    fail_10=(t.fail_10 * 0.1),
    fail_12=(t.fail_12 * 0.1),
    fail_14=(t.fail_14 * 0.1),
    fail_16=(t.fail_16 * 0.1),
    fail_18=(t.fail_18 * 0.1),
    fail_sa=(t.fail_sa * 0.1),
    result='',
    contactdate=NULL,
    USER='',
         status="Verify",
         entrydate=now()
WHERE t.status='New'
    AND t.result='match'
    AND t.locked_for=''
    AND t.contactdate < (now()-interval 5 MINUTE)
    AND t.client_id=123
    AND t.campaign_id = 1
```

So, in 99,99 % of the cases, the update works and all values are updated where they should be.

However, there have been two cases where 2 of the 15 columns did **not** update even though they should have. And also, in those two cases, the other columns of the same row **did** update. It's as if something prevented updating some of the columns, but there were no errors thrown by MariaDB or any logging we have in place.

Any idea how that is possible? If there was a lock or deadlock, nothing would be updated in the row?

Comment: Does the table have any triggers?  Do the rows get updated if you run the query a second time?

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think that some columns are not being updated while others are?  Also, your update query only specifies 13 fields to be updated.

Comment: @DanBracuk we have a log of the changes in the rows, where you can see the old and new status after each update. In that, normally all values are updated as expected, but in these two cases, two columns did not update even though they should have. The column **result** should be empty instead of having the value "match", and the column **list** should have the value "list@client" instead of "imported@client"

Comment: @DanBracuk oh and for example **workflow_id** got a value (it starts as empty), and **contactdate** became NULL as expected. **entrydate** was updated from the old datetime value to current datetime.

Comment: Could another connection have made changes "at the same time"?